# Parsing output / how to parse output using powershell

Tags: powershell, parsing, scripting

I am trying to parse an output of get-hotfix
I am getting something like this

{\DESKTOP-abc\xyz\qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq.HotFixID="123" "}

I just need HotFixID="123"

Please help. 
Thank you

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to parse anything from Get-Hotfix, it returns proper objects like all Powershell cmdlets, you just select the properties you want and it'll give them to you. Post your code and it'll probably become clearer what's going wrong.

Comment: `get-hotfix | select hotfixid`.  It's not obvious?

Comment: Yeah that worked.. I was using select string that was causing problem I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about regex matching and subsequent use of $matches, but what you're really after appears to be this:

`(Get-Hotfix).HotFixId`

Nice and easy, since HotFixId is one of the properties of the items returned by Get-Hotfix.